# How can I modify all request url from CWebBrowser control?

Tags: browser, proxy, mfc

I'm going to develop a web browser to control request. I'm using CWebBrowser2(MFC) and that class is very simple and useful. Now I have to control the whole request from web browser. For example, the user request the url "http://www.aaa.com", I want to change that url to "http://127.0.0.1/url.html?url=http://www.aaa.com". It must apply a whole request, even static content(image, etc). It it possible? It seems like web proxy. But I can't modify CWebBrowser2 class provided MS. Is there any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a handler to catch the request before the browser control processes it:

```
void OnBeforeNavigate2(LPDISPATCH pDisp, VARIANT FAR* URL, VARIANT FAR* Flags, VARIANT FAR* TargetFrameName, VARIANT FAR* PostData, VARIANT FAR* Headers, BOOL FAR* Cancel);

ON_EVENT(CWebBrowser2, IDC_BROWSER, 250 /* BeforeNavigate2 */, _OnBeforeNavigate2, VTS_DISPATCH **VTS_PVARIANT** VTS_PVARIANT VTS_PVARIANT VTS_PVARIANT VTS_PVARIANT VTS_PBOOL)
```

Look at the source for void `CDHtmlDialog::_OnBeforeNavigate2` for more guidance.